# Is $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ free as a $\mathbb{Z}$ module

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show whether $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is free as a $\mathbb{Z}$ module. I'm sure it isn't, but I'm struggling with a formal proof.

My initial thoughts were that if $\mathbb{Z}+x$ is in a basis then $\mathbb{Z}+\frac{x}{2}$ is in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ but not in the $\mathbb{Z}$-span of $\mathbb{Z}+x$, so we would need to add it to the basis. But then they wouldn't be linearly independent. This clearly is not a proper proof, since I haven't shown that $\mathbb{Z}+\frac{x}{2}$ is not in the $\mathbb{Z}$-span of the other basis elements. Any tips for a better approach?

Comment: There is no much that your argument is missing. If $x_i, i\in I$ is a basis, then $x_0/2=\sum_i a_ix_i$ for some integers $a_i$ that are all zero except finitely many, then $0=-x_0+\sum_i2a_ix_i$. This implies that all $a_i=0$ except $a_0$ which would satisfy $2a_0-1=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ has torsion.